# Rails will_paginate persistence

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, activerecord

Is there a way to make the results persist across the `will_paginate` pages?  I'm listing reports through a given range with `bootstrap-datepicker-rails`, which posts the results for a range, but then when I click on the page 2 link, it reverts back to what the results would be on page 2 without the range.

Here's what I have:

**views/reports/index.html.erb**

```html
<%= render partial: "pages/navigation" %>

  <div class="row reports">
      <div class="col-md-2 sidebar no-float">
        <h3 class="text-center">Select Date Range</h3>
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
          <%= form_tag reports_index_path, method: :post, :class => "form-inline" do %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag "Start Date:" %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, @reports.blank? ? '' : params[:start_date], class: "form-control", name: "start_date", data: {"behaviour" => "datepicker"}) %>
            <p class="text-center">to</p>
            <%= label_tag "End Date:" %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, @reports.blank? ? '' : params[:end_date], class: "form-control", name: "end_date", data: {"behaviour" => "datepicker"}) %>
          </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "update-button" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-10 report-list no-float">
        <h2 class="text-center">Reports Archive</h2>
        <% @reports.in_groups_of(3).each do |group| %>
          <ul id="report-list list">
              <% group.each do |report| %>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <li class="report">
                    <div class="report-header">
                      <p>
                        <span class="report-data"><%= report.name %></span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="report-text"><%= report.range %></p>
                    <p class="report-text"><%= link_to "Download", report.pdf.url, target: "_blank" %></p>
                  </li>
                </div>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
<!-- </div> -->

<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <%= will_paginate @reports, :previous_label => "Newer", :next_label => "Older", :params => { :start_date => params[:start_date], :end_date => params[:end_date] } %>
</div>


<%= render partial: "pages/footer" %>
```

**controllers/reports_controller.rb**

```html
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @company = current_user.company

    @locations = if @company
      current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
    else
      []
    end

    unless @company.nil? || @company.reports.empty?
      if request.post?
        @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: report_params[:start_date]..report_params[:end_date]).order(created_at: :asc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      else
        if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
          @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: (report_params[:start_date]..report_params[:end_date])).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
        else
          @reports = @company.reports.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def report_params
      params.permit(:start_date, :end_date)
    end

end
```

**This is fixed**So, by default I'm loading all available reports if the request isn't a `post`, which I assume is the issue since clicking to page 2 isn't a post.

**This isn't fixed** Whenever I click on the last page after defining a range it always returns an error, even though there are still records left to show.

Here's what the default page looks like when loaded (without range specified yet):

[image: Default Report Page]

Then here's what it looks like when I define a range of (5/1/15 - 7/1/15) on Page 1:

[image: Defined Range]

Page #2-10 work without an issue:

[image: Pages 2-10]

But the last page always does this, as if will_paginate is adding an extra page for some reason:

[image: Error on last page]

Comment: Your filtering is submitted as `POST` which doesn't exists when you click a pagination link. You can make the filter form to be submitted in `GET` and persists those in will_paginate links. You can customize `LinkRenderer` to persist the query parameters.

Comment: Is there an example of doing this anywhere?  Is it a `will_paginate` override, or for the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters to will_paginate using the `:params` options.

In your particular case, you could do the following:

```
<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <%= will_paginate @reports, :previous_label => "Newest", :next_label => "Oldest", :params => { :start_date => @start_date, :end_date => @end_date } %>
</div>
```

and amend the controller like this:

```
unless @company.nil? || @company.reports.empty?
  if request.post?
    @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: report_params[:start_date]..report_params[:end_date]).order(created_at: :asc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    @start_date, @end_date = @reports.last.created_at, @reports.first.created_at
  else
    if params[:start_date].present? && params[:end_date].present?
      @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: (params[:start_date]..params[:end_date])).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      @start_date, @end_date = params[:start_date], params[:end_date]
    else
      @reports = @company.reports.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      @start_date, @end_date = @reports.first.created_at, @reports.last.created_at
    end
  end
end
```

Note: not sure which of `start_date` or `end_date` is anterior to the other, you probably want to make sure the range is defined correctly, i.e. (oldest..most recent)

Added fix to the `reports` iteration:

```
          <% group.each do |report| %>
            <% unless report.nil? %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <li class="report">
                <div class="report-header">
                  <p>
                    <span class="report-data"><%= report.name %></span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <p class="report-text"><%= report.range %></p>
                <p class="report-text"><%= link_to "Download", report.pdf.url, target: "_blank" %></p>
              </li>
            </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: start_date would be the older date, end_date is the newer.  I like the suggestion as it makes it easier, however it's throwing an error `undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass` on the will_paginate line now after doing what you suggested.

Comment: That means either `@reports.first` or `@reports.last` is `nil`, which in turn means `@reports` itself is `nil` (or empty). Is that a possibility?

Comment: I just expanded the range, which should include 60+ reports, with 15 to a page, there should be results on the other pages.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's wrong. When the `@reports` collection is updated, the `end_date` and `start_date` are updated to the dates of the first and last reports in the current segment. That cannot work. Let me edit the code with a workaround ;)

Comment: Ok, using your suggestions, I modified the code and it seems to be working, with one minor glitch: the last page in `will_paginate` always generates an error.  I updated all the code below and added a screenshot.

Comment: From page 1 to n-1, you will always have 30 reports, so your `in_groups_of(3)` method will always return an array of 3 reports. However, on the last page, you might have a number of reports that's not a multiple of 3. In that case, the last iteration of the `in_groups_of(3)` method will return an array with one or two reports and two or one `nil` values. When you iterate the array and attempt to access the `name` attribute of `nil`, the error is thrown.

Comment: See updated answer for a solution to your last page error.

Comment: Prefecto!  Jaxx, you're the bomb!